# Wait server for 70 seconds

Tags: android, multithreading, sockets, tcp, client

I'm new in this forum. I've made a TCP Client in Android with a thread. This code is working for my app:

```
  class TCPClient extends Thread
 {
     String add;

     public TCPClient(String IPa)
     {
       add=IPa;
     }

     public void run()
     {
         try
         {
             InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(add);
             socket = new Socket(serverAddr, SERVERPORT);

             //write part: i write to server
             PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())),true);
             out.print("INIT");
             out.flush();

            //read part: I receive a message from server

            byte[] bytes = new byte[1000];


             StringBuilder x = new StringBuilder();

             int numRead = 0;
             if ((numRead = socket.getInputStream().read(bytes)) >= 0)
             {
               x.append(new String(bytes, 0, numRead));
             }

             if(x.toString().equals("INIT_ACK"))
                 //position_req();
              getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                  public void run()
                  {
                   Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),"Connesso",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                  }
              });
         }

         catch (UnknownHostException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
         } catch (IOException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
         } catch (Exception e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
         }


     }
```

But I have this problem: the server maybe answers after 70 seconds, so I need to put a waiting control and listen if the server send me an answer.
How can I do it?
Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
socket.setSoTimeout(70*1000);
```

So, your approach will work fine. First Android app I did in 2009 we used this approach. Many apps and architects and teams hating it and wanting AsyncTask which was various flopped around WRT to how it handled threads, and fast-forward to a few months ago when our high-priced mobile consultancy we contracted to dropped Async task and went to a thread model. LOL. They use Otto instead of runOnUIThread, but same diff.
Good luck!